# Bad chars in gnome-terminal vim

Tags: linux, vim, gnome-terminal

I'm using Fedora 17 with gnome-shell. I've installed Ubuntu fonts, and I'm running vim inside the gnome-terminal.

Quote often, I get the following problem:

[image: Vim screenshot]

What could be the problem? The problem happens during cursor movements (either by arrows or by the usual hjkl).

If I go to the other parts of the file, and get back to this section, these chars are gone. This also happens with other fonts (Monaco comes to mind). Also, this doesn't happen in GVIM with the same settings (font selection + size, color theme)

Answer (score 1):

What's the output of `$ echo $TERM` in GT and `:echo $TERM` in Vim?

I've had this issue in the past (with tmux) and worked around it by adding the following lines to my `~/.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <Esc>A <up>
nnoremap <Esc>B <down>
nnoremap <Esc>C <right>
nnoremap <Esc>D <left>
inoremap <Esc>A <up>
inoremap <Esc>B <down>
inoremap <Esc>C <right>
inoremap <Esc>D <left>
```

Comment: The output in both is 'screen'.

Comment: I tried the suggested configuration, and it does make it happen less, but still not completely solved.

Comment: Are you actually running screen? If not, I doubt that's the correct $TERM setting.

Comment: As I said, I'm running tmux. What would be the right TERM settings then?

Comment: You didn't say anything about tmux. Try this in your `.tux.conf`: `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"`.

Comment: @romainl sorry, I misread the answer as my own post. I didn't say tmux before.

Comment: ...and the tip didn't help.

Comment: And that was `.tmux.conf`. You said the problem is not completely solved: could you describe precisely what is happening, where, when?

Comment: @romainl sure;
I tried other terminals (guake, konsole) with or without tmux - it is still the same problem; I have also changed the font - still the same. I'm starting to think that the problem is actually in vim, not the terminal.
Additionally, I just checked that running \vi on the same file seems to work fine, so it is probably something in my settings...

Comment: @romainl I just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987317/while-moving-the-cursor-across-a-vim-process-open-in-a-tmux-session-every-now-a
; and we have a duplicate :-)

Comment: Hmm… yeah I thought I already answered a similar question. This problem seems to be quite common as it's discussed a lot in many places. Those lines above are in my `~/.vimrc` since a year or so and I've never seen these escape sequences again after that. Commenting these lines and launching another Vim session doesn't seem to bring them back, it seems. Weird.

Comment: @romainl yea, the problem is apparently in parsing the branch name I'm in (git) and showing it on the statusline. I used my custom function for that, and was using the Powerline plugin. When I removed using my custom function and went back to fugitive, it solved the problem. Weird indeed.